# inserting multiple rows into a table want to understand the process of what is happening or not happening

Tags: php, mysql, loops, insert

hello I'm trying to insert values from an array using PHP into multiple rows in a mysql table.

this is basically what i'm doing:

```
$x=0;

while($x < 40){ <----the 40 is the size of the array

$nameinsert=$name[$x];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('','$nameinsert')";

$x++;
}
return mysql_query($sql);
```

obviously solutions would be great, but my main question is why doesn't this work? why does it only insert the last value from the array?

from what i can tell it should:

get the value from the array
insert into the the table
increase value $x 
then get the next value from the array 
then insert that into the table

so why doesn't it?

Comment: PHP Processes from the top down. your while statement must execute 40 times before any code outside of the WHILE block will be triggered. Therefore by the time you touch `$sql` it's been propagated with the last iteration from your while statement. if you want to insert it multiple times, put it in the while function and remove the return. Also, **please don't use** the `mysql_` library and consider switching to `mysqli` or `pdo`. Also consider using `count(array)` instead of hard coding values.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('','$nameinsert')"`: **never do this**! See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/372643).

Comment: Thank you, i do use count(array) i just use the number for the example, but now i understand it - i didn't realise the mysql_query($sql) was need ed for each execution, but just at the end when i had finished. but it works fine now. and yes i will look into mysqli although i don't know exactly why yet but i'm sure i'll find out.

Comment: Why not have a single multiple insert like `INSERT INTO mytable (cola, colb) VALUES('','$nameinsert'), ('','$nameinsert')`

Comment: @user2975156, the reason why you need to look into `mysqli` is that it allows for parametrised queries. Yours isn't, you're injecting the parameter straight into the query string: this is a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write where the code insert the values in which column try like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable('name of column') VALUES('value here');
```

Also i don't know why did you let an empty value !

So the question is why does it insert only the last value?

because you are putting the execution of query out of while loop try like this

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('', ?)");
if ($stmt) {
    while($x < 40){ <----the 40 is the size of the array
        $nameinsert = $name[$x];
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $nameinsert);
        $stmt->execute();

        $x++;
   }

   $stmt->close();
}
```

Now what happen?

it goes for the first value it will add it and execute the query by mysql_query() after that it increase the value and it will execute the seconde value....etc

Comment: thanks, i see my mistake now, i was really getting frustrated not knowing why it wasn't working but it doe now, works like a charm, thank you so much.

Comment: It's a shame there's still a big security hole in this answer (like any one that uses `mysql_query` and puts the parameters in the query string directly).

Comment: Well i know their is an SQL INJECTION :) to privent this i will fix the code thank you, of course i answred about the question he didn't ask about security

Comment: Too bad `mysql_real_escape_string` [isn't the way to fix this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/372643).

Comment: hello bruno, i don't see where the security issue is, although i do understand mysqli is more secure, all the variables going into the table are created by me the user doesn't and can't put anything into the table, but i am starting to read up about mysqli thanks. walid - how do i accept an answer, do you mean vote for it?

Comment: Please edit the code for the right answer :) so we can learn from you and thank you

Comment: @user2975156, you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/372643). Essentially, the problem is that `$nameinsert` could contain SQL statements (e.g. `"'); DELETE FROM mytable; --"`), which would mean you're actually running `"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('',''); DELETE FROM mytable;"`. `mysql_real_escape_string` is often used as a workaround, but [it's still flawed in general](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/372643) unfortunately. Just use `mysqli` or PDO. (Of course use `mysqli` *with* parametrised queries, not just the same string again.)

Comment: @WalidNaceri, probably best if you edit your own answer.

Comment: @Bruno well this is my knowledge I'm also learning, if you can edit it for a best one it will be better so we can learn

Comment: @WalidNaceri, I haven't tried this code (so there might be typos), but this should be the idea. (Another general SQL recommendation: name the columns you insert into, e.g. `INSERT INTO (column1, column2) VALUES (...)`, so that you don't get surprises if for some reason, later in the evolution of the application, the order of the columns change.)

Comment: well thank you @Bruno really and i tried it its working also :) it is really nice if you can post for us a video or a tutorials to see how tha hackers can bybass the      mysql_real_escape_string();

Comment: Go through the answers I've linked to, in particular http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/372643